# Usar S@T CF-e com android

Tags: java, android, xml, erp

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo em android que se comunique com o dispositivo SAT-CF que veio para substituir o ECF (Emissor de Cupom Fiscal).

Porem nao sei como comecar nem como fazer isso, alguem encontrou algum tutorial ou pode me auxiliar em como trabalhar com SAT em android / java

Comment: Só uma correção: o SAT não veio para substituir o ECF, o SAT veio para substituir a fonte de renda dos fabricantes de ECF, pois na prática, a NFC-e funciona muito bem sem SAT nos outros estados. Voltando à pergunta, você já sabe trabalhar com o SAT em desktop? Seria fundamental entender como trabalhar com aquela gambiarra, digo, tecnologia, pra depois aplicar no android.